# Enable Yellow Screen of Death on MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, yellow-screen-of-death

I had to take over an MVC 3 project from another developer.  One of the first things he did was to stop the yellow screen of death so that all exceptions are only logged to a file.  You now only get a generic message saying an error has occurred.

I would like to switch it back on (since it gets really annoying having to check through the logfiles the whole time) - how do I do this.

I checked through the web.config but I can't see where this happens.

I did try doing customerrors=off, but that didn't do anything.  Also removed the global error handling attribute, didn't do anything.

On further clarification, it seems if an exception occurs in a controller I do get the yellow screen of death, but if it occurs in a (razor) view I just get a standard generic error.

You can see the web.config [here](http://pastebin.com/GzGVLbVs)
You can see the global.asax [here](http://pastebin.com/6irKKrkP)

Comment: My guess is that he implemented a global exception handler. If that's what he did, all you need to do is unhook the handler, and you should get your yellow screen back. You can read about it here:  http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/961301/Global-Exception-Handling-with-ASPNET.htm

Comment: I checked - there is no global exception handler being registered in global.asax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Global.asax` you can remove `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());` from `public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)`.

As pointed out in the comments - the problem was with a Custom Base controller overriding the OnException Method.

Comment: Can you please paste your web.config and Global.asax?

Comment: @Jaco, OK, What does the Action look like that throws the exception?

Comment: It wasn't an action throwing the exception.  I actually checked it now - if an action throws the exception I do get YSOD, but if an error occurs in the view it fails...

Comment: @Jaco, You mean a runtime exception? If you step through the View, where does it give you an error?

Comment: Well it doesn't really matter does it?  If I put something like @{ throw Exception("bob"); } into my view, I should see that exception

Comment: Yes it should display an error page. Does your Controller derive from some custom class that has any overrides on the i.e. OnActionExecuting or any of those execution methods?

Comment: How come you can debug my code better than me? :-)  Thanks Filip - I updated your answer to include your comment.

Comment: @FilipEkberg I have a project in my hand, this wasn't there and I off the CustomError and I still didn't see YSOD.

Answer (score 6):

This question is a little old, but maybe this will help someone.  In addition to setting `<customerErrors mode="Off" />`, also set this under `<system.webServer>`: `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />`

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 5):

Normally you set this in web.config in the `customErrors` element under `system.web`.
Just try to set mode=Off:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Answer (score 1):

None of this worked for me. Check if someone might have added code to clear the error in the application error event handler.

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception lastException = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

        Log.Error("Global.asax: WebApplication error", lastException);

        //****Server.ClearError();
    }
```